# robolelectric setup issue -- how to start with roboelectric framework

Tags: android, android-testing, gradle-android-test-plugi

I am starting with Robolectric framework 3.0. for android testing. I am goingthrough there site and they mention the first step as adding in build gradle

> testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"

I have done that and did a complete clean build.
Now once I start writing my first test case I get comilation issue-- cannot find symbol class RunWith for the annotation @

> RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)

Please tell me, what I am missing? I thought mavencentral() will download the respective jar file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is ur package of roboeltric importing in android code?

Comment: Thank You, It was simple mistake of missed imports and the test folder name :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Robolectric-Installation-for-Unit-Testing) link.

Make sure your test case locations are proper.

Android Studio defaults to looking for tests in the following locations:
Unit Tests => src/test/java

Comment: Can you also check -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867722/android-roboelectric-3-0-testing-next-activity-choosing-from-multiple-activities